# How to write a search query when to search two filename in two different columns in the table

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE filename LIKE '%" . 
$searchq . "%' OR filename1 LIKE '%" .
$searchq . "%' AND category = '" . $_SESSION['action']."'") or 
die ("could not search");
```

Every time my query gives the output Could not search!!

where `$table` is variable for `table_name`, `filename` and `filename1` are `filednames` of the same table respectively.

Thank you .

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Try by giving the table name instead of the $table and let me know.

Comment: Instead of (or at least before) `die()`, please call [`mysql_error()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_error) to see the actual error you're getting. Post the query you're running (e.g., echo the query after substituting the parameters) and the error message so we can see the exact problem.

Comment: Format your query better here and also in your own code. This a lot of time helps in finding out the problems. Also use `mysql_error()` to find out the actual problem

Comment: Thnx for the suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You will have a syntax problem, try:

```
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE (filename LIKE '%$searchq%' OR filename1 LIKE '%$searchq%') AND category = '" .$_SESSION['action']."'" ) or die (mysql_error()) ;
```

Comment: Sir could you please simplyfy I couldnot get you

Comment: I updated my answer, you will have a syntax error, I change the end of line, I added: **die(mysql_error())**

Comment: Outlining "where" the syntax error was, would be beneficial for the OP and others who visit this Q&A.

Comment: Unknown column 'filename1' in 'where clause' this is the syntax error now

Comment: Ok, it's because you don't have column **filename1** in your table

Comment: I have that column sir in my table. itz a language table where i have to upload two types of file a wav file and a txt grid file with filename and filename1 and filesize and filesize1

Comment: Ok, please recheck your table, chech if you have exacly the same column name "filename1", MySQL are raising this error.

Comment: `Unknown column 'filename1'` means you do not have that column in the table that you are querying from.

Comment: Ok sir i am checkin and let you know soon

Comment: thnk you sir I got the solution. yes the database table fileldname was changed from filename1 to txtfile dats y it was nt matching!!!